# Way to get Selenium standalone jars using IVY

Tags: java, maven, selenium

Is there any way to get Selenium standalone and client combined Java 3.4.0 jars using IVY? I can see, selenium stopped publishing full jar through Maven (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium) but I will need it to overcome some of the issues with our internal code if we use it separate jars.

Also, is there a good way to get Selenium standalone jar through Ivy? (`<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-server" rev="3.4.0"/>`).

For example:

```
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-server" rev="3.4.0"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed issues with internal code if we use separate jars as there is no way to get standalone jars, here is the solution:

## Dependency of httpcomponents - which is needed to launch the browsers:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-exec" rev="1.3"/>

<dependency org="org.apache.httpcomponents" name="httpclient" rev="4.5.3"/>

<dependency org="org.apache.httpcomponents" name="httpcore" rev="4.4.6"/>
```

## Get selenium server, java, api and drivers:

```
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-api" rev="3.4.0"/>

<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-chrome-driver" rev="3.4.0"/>

<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-edge-driver" rev="3.4.0"/>

<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-firefox-driver" rev="3.4.0"/>

<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-ie-driver" rev="3.4.0"/>

<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-java" rev="3.4.0"/>

<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-remote-driver" rev="3.4.0"/>

<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-safari-driver" rev="3.4.0"/>

<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-server" rev="3.4.0"/>

<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-support" rev="3.4.0"/>
```

Also take a look:

```
https://github.com/Ardesco/selenium-standalone-server-plugin
https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
```